# Vlookup Formula Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel File Image]

Hi Everyone, Please have a look on **Cell D2**. I have tried the Formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$B$8:$D$12,3)
```

But it doesn't give the Result i.e. I require **04 Values** as **I have written there Manually** but it's giving only **01 Value**. I think an Array Formula might work but don't know.

Comment: This will help: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/ You can return multiple values as rows/columns.

Comment: VLOOKUP returns the first found result. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288782/excel-index-match-multiple-row-results) may be of use

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP will not work as it will only return one answer.

You will want TEXTJOIN as an array formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($B$8:$B$12 = B2,$D$8:$D$12,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

If you do not have Office 365 Excel and still want the values in one cell like your example you will need vba.

Comment: Scott, I know about TEXTJOIN but I need to include Vlookup or Array inside the Formula as I have to import data from other Sheets in different Workbooks

Comment: The IF iterates and returns all that match.  That is what the array portion does.  You would just change the references to match what you needed.

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(104),TRUE,IF(auto!L62:L65=G808,auto!N62:N65,""))

Comment: A notice, @TalhaRasheed your formula differ against Scott's. You use `CHAR(104)` instead of `CHAR(10)`...