# Excel formula to get the first three non-zero values and get the corresponding headers of them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 12 columns with 0,1 inside. I have put them headers the name of months. I am trying to get the first three, 1 , from left to right and get the corresponding header in column 13, 14, 15 .

I started with the following but I get only the first header.

```
=INDEX(B$2:M$2;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B3:M3<>0;);0))
```

How can I do it? thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you show some sample data with the expected output?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288782/excel-index-match-multiple-row-results) may be of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in N3 and copy over:

```
=INDEX($2:$2,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($B3:$M3)/($B3:$M3<>0),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

[image]

Comment: Its working its working :) can you explain me how its work?

Comment: Did you change the `,` to `;` for your local settings?

Comment: @MariaGeorgali it is for you.  but for me it does not work with `;`.  It only works with `,`